# VSTS Build definition - Store secret with special character removes characters automatically

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In VSTS Build definition (for building Xamarin.Android project in Mac Build Agent) the keystore password is added as a secret in Build variables tab. The TFS is automatically stripping of double quotes and convert "\" to "/"

Can someone tell me how to escape these characters?

Comment: What's the variable value like? How do you use it? I just made a test with a powershell to send the variable value to web api, it won't convert "\" to "/".

Comment: =j6q"~.Mvy\!<4~V . try this

Comment: How do you use the variable? Try it with single quotes, such as =j6q'"'~.Mvy'\'!<4~V.

Comment: I am using the VSTS build variables which tokenize the password into a variable. So would expect VSTS build to take care of such things rather we manually escaping or adding string representation of password.

Comment: Which task you used to tokenize the password? (I just test with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens on windows agent and can use =j6q"~.Mvy\!<4~V directly). On the other hand, what's the result of =j6q'"'~.Mvy'\'!<4~V?

Comment: I used MSBuild command line.

Comment: Can you provide a sample?